# how to search using BETWEEN in sql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, between

how to search using **Between** in **mysql** in **vb.net**?

i tried some codes but its not working.

here is the sample database:

```
 ___________________________
|            date           |
-----------------------------
|Wednesday, December 4, 2013|
-----------------------------

here is my code in vb.net:

Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE date BETWEEN '" & dtepicker1.text & "' and '" & dtepicker2.text & "'"

Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand

With sqlcmd
    .CommandText = sqlquery
    .Connection = connectionsrvr
End With
```

Comment: First of all, you must use `dtepicker1.Value` and not text property! Second, create a `SqlReader` to reads your commands results. Third, do not compose queries manually, but use `Parameters` instead!

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
"SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE date BETWEEN '" & dtepicker1.Value & "' and '" & dtepicker2.Value & "'"
```

<strike>and just another alternative..</strike>

<strike>"SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE date > '" & dtepicker1.text & "' AND date <'" & dtepicker2.text & "'"</strike>